# Python: Referring to 'self' between two classes

Tags: python, function, class, callback, self

I am working on creating a Civilization-esque game, and as part of that, I'm trying to implement a government mechanic.

Class 'Controller' handles (amongst other things) the interface. When I click on the button 'government', a bunch of buttons appear, that should let me select my preferred government.

Function 'drawInterface(self)', part of 'class Controller()', does many things, amongst which creating the button that creates the government menu. This is not relevant for this question, in my opinion, but I'm including it here for completeness' sake:

```
class Controller():
    def drawInterface(self):
        Controller.buttons.add(Button('Government', colourinactive=eval(Civilisationdb.get(Civilisationdb.active == 1).colour1), colourhover=eval(Civilisationdb.get(Civilisationdb.active == 1).colour1), colouractive=eval(Civilisationdb.get(Civilisationdb.active == 1).colour1), colouroutline=eval(Civilisationdb.get(Civilisationdb.active == 1).colour2), rect=pygame.Rect(384, 64, 256, 32), callback=self.toGovernment, text='Government', textcolour=eval(Civilisationdb.get(Civilisationdb.active == 1).colour2)))
```

When clicking on this button, function 'toGovernment(self)', part of 'class Controller()', creates dozens of buttons that allow you to choose your preferred government - I have only included one button in this example:

```
class Controller():
    def toGovernment(self):
        if Controller.interfacemenu != 'Government':
            Controller.interfacemenustructure.add(Button('Hegemony', colourinactive=eval(Civilisationdb.get(Civilisationdb.active == 1).colour1), colourhover=eval(Civilisationdb.get(Civilisationdb.active == 1).colour1), colouractive=eval(Civilisationdb.get(Civilisationdb.active == 1).colour1), colouroutline=eval(Civilisationdb.get(Civilisationdb.active == 1).colour2), rect=pygame.Rect(64, 160, 160, 32), callback=lambda:Civilisation.selectGovernment('Structure','Hegemony'), text='Hegemony', fontsize=12, textcolour=eval(Civilisationdb.get(Civilisationdb.active == 1).colour2), toggleactive=True))
```

And so there are many more buttons that you can see in the screenshot below (the code above creates the button 'Hegemony' in category 'Structure'):
[image]
Then, we move to 'class Civilisation()' for the function 'selectGovernment(type, name):

```
    def selectGovernment(type, name):
        if type == 'Structure':
            self.structurecivic = name
        elif type == 'Government':
            self.governmentcivic = name
        elif type == 'Economy':
            self.economycivic = name
        elif type == 'Foreign':
            self.foreigncivic = name
        elif type == 'Military':
            self.militarycivic = name
        elif type == 'Religion':
            self.religioncivic = name
        changeGovernment(self.structurecivic, self.governmentcivic, self.economycivic, self.foreigncivic, self.militarycivic) #self.religioncivic
```

Here, Python throws an error that 'self' is not defined. Right above this function, I declare the following as part of the class's init:

```
        self.civilisationid = Civilisationdb.select(Civilisationdb.civilisationid).where(Civilisationdb.civilisation == self.civilisation, Civilisationdb.leader == self.leader)
        self.structurecivic = Civilisationdb.select(Civilisationdb.structurecivic).where(Civilisationdb.civilisationid == self.civilisationid)
        self.governmentcivic = Civilisationdb.select(Civilisationdb.governmentcivic).where(Civilisationdb.civilisationid == self.civilisationid)
        self.economycivic = Civilisationdb.select(Civilisationdb.economycivic).where(Civilisationdb.civilisationid == self.civilisationid)
        self.foreigncivic = Civilisationdb.select(Civilisationdb.foreigncivic).where(Civilisationdb.civilisationid == self.civilisationid)
        self.militarycivic = Civilisationdb.select(Civilisationdb.militarycivic).where(Civilisationdb.civilisationid == self.civilisationid)
        #self.religioncivic = Civilisationdb.select(Civilisationdb.religioncivic).where(Civilisationdb.civilisationid == self.civilisationid)
```

Presumably, Python interprets the 'self' as referring to 'class Controller()', and not to 'class Civilisation()'. I have played around with various ways of writing these functions, but to no avail. How would I fix this? What am I misunderstanding?

Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: def selectGovernment(type, name): - the first argument should be self

Comment: Then you get the error:  
  
TypeError: selectGovernment() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'  
  
And if you adjust that function to:  
  
callback=lambda:Civilisation.selectGovernment(self,'Structure','Hegemony')  
  
The 'self' will keep referring to 'class Controller()'. The consequence of that is that the 'changeGovernment' function needs to be called as 'Civilisation.changeGovernment', and if you do that, you get the error:  
  
AttributeError: 'Controller' object has no attribute 'governmentcivic'